# Laravel how to get users based on model exists or not

Tags: php, laravel

In my `laravel`-application I want to display a list of all users/candidates. So far I have this, which basically works fine:

```
public function candidates()
{
    $users = User::whereHas(
        'roles',
        function ($q) {
            $q->where('slug', 'candidates');
        }
    )->get();

    return response(['success' => true, "users" => $users], 200);
}
```

Now, I actually want to display users/candidates who have taken an education. I have a Model called `UserEducation` but I don't really know to include it to get the data out I want.

can someone help me out?

**EDIT**

In my User model, I have this relation:

```
public function educations()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\UserEducation');
}
```

Comment: just another whereHas('educations', ... with filter where education is taken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [has](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence):

```
 $users = User::has('UserEducation')->whereHas(
        'roles',
        function ($q) {
            $q->where('slug', 'candidates');
        }
    )->get();
```

Comment: This works not 100%. ` $users = User::has('UserEducation')->get()` would give me all users with educations, but chained with `whereHas` I get an empty array...

Comment: are you sure you have (candidates) slug in your roles table?

Answer (score 0):

You can try create relationship with User and UserEducation models and then get data.
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Yes, I already did that... please check my updated question.

Comment: You can try something like this:


`$users = User::whereHas('roles', function ($q) {$q->where('slug', 'candidates');})->with('educations')->get();`